# Integrated terminal in Visual Studio Code displays smaller than normal

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

I used Visual Studio Code on macOS. The integrated terminal displays text very small. I have not knowingly changed any settings related to the terminal. How can I fix this?

[image: vs code integrated terminal]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open Code settings (`Cmd+,`) and add `"terminal.integrated.fontSize": 20,` to your custom settings (right side).